# How to link homebrew gcc-4.x to gcc?

Tags: macos, gcc, executable, homebrew

In OS X, how can I link gcc-4.8 from homebrew to gcc? I already tried to link gcc-4.8 to /usr/local/bin/gcc but this does not work. I really need this because I have shared makefiles in a course at the university.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least a couple of options.

1. I have my GCC 4.8.2 installed under `/usr/gcc/v4.8.2` and I ensure that `/usr/gcc/v4.8.2/bin` is on my `PATH` ahead of `/usr/bin`.  That way, the undecorated name `gcc` means GCC 4.8.2.  (This is on Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks, just for the record.)
2. Specify CC=`/usr/gcc/v4.8.2/bin/gcc` on command lines, etc.  Painful, so I don't regard it as a real option.
3. Make `/usr/bin/gcc` point to `/usr/gcc/v4.8.2/bin/gcc` instead of being an executable that runs `clang`.

I distrust modifying `/usr/bin` or `/bin` (or `/sbin` or `/usr/sbin`).  I seldom use the system-provided Perl, for example, but always use my own build, using the same general technique.

Comment: 2nd is no option. 3rd seems not to be the way to do it. 1st seems to be what I was looking for. PATH is set in /etc/paths and /etc/paths.d/